# iOS 8.2 not supported in Xcode 6.3 beta

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8.2, xcode6.3

As stated in the title, upgraded today to iOS 8.2 and my device is not supported in Xcode 6.3 beta.

Even though Xcode 6.3 supports iOS 8.3, I also cannot install iOS 8.2 simulator.

I cannot quit using Xcode 6.3 beta because I have quite of a lot of code modified according to Swift 1.2 changes and as far as I know Xcode 6.2 does not yet support Swift 1.2.

Is there any known solution except downgrading or upgrading to iOS 8.3 beta? (also iOS 8.3 beta was not to be found along apple links for download)

P.S.. I was able to run Swift code on the device prior to upgrade..

Answer (score 27, accepted):

After installing Xcode 6.2 also released this days, I opened a random project, it signed (or did something with my device) and after that Xcode 6.3 beta recognised my iOS 8.2 version!

1. Install the last stable Xcode version
2. open a random project
3. connect your device while keeping the Xcode opened
4. let Xcode make it's own procedures for recognising the device ("copy symbols"..)
5. open your beta Xcode and enjoy using your test device as always

Comment: Lucky. But now you know why you don't modify important code with a beta release of tools. I am also looking forward to Swift 1.2 enhancements but can't use them until it's released.

Comment: you are right. Do you have some useful links on how to assure swift 1.1 vs swift 1.2 compatibility?

Comment: Thank you, Fawkes. I had Xcode 6.1 and 6.3 on my MacBook and iOS 8.1 on my iPhone. After I upgraded my iPhone to iOS 8.2, Xcode 6.3 stopped recognizing my iPhone. I installed Xcode 6.2, launched it with my iPhone plugged in, selected my iPhone as the deployment target, waited it for Xcode to do its business, quit, launched Xcode 6.3, and was able to deploy my app to my iPhone.

Comment: I really think you just have to be 1.1-only, except for your isolated, non-essential exploratory projects, until 1.2 is properly released then switch over. You could be even more cautious and wait a while longer...

Comment: I tested your approach with Xcode 5.1 & Xcode 6.3 beta and it worked!

Answer (score 10):

The fix is: Go to Product > Destination, and even though it says your device is ineligible, it will still allow you to select it, then building to it will work.

Comment: Absolutely!  Thanks this is the correct and super easy fix

Answer (score 2):

This worked after I installed latest beta today:
Open Xcode 6.2 and go to Devices. Connect your iPhone and wait for the spinner to finish (some minutes in my case). Close 6.2 and re-open 6.3. Now it should work!

Thanks to Christian Zangl on the Apple Developer forum!

Answer (score 1):

The Apple Release Notes says:

iOS beta Support
• Devices running iOS 8.2 is not supported in Xcode 6.3 beta 2. (19867597)

You can see it [here](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/Xcode_6.3_beta_2/Xcode_6.3_beta_2_Release_Notes.pdf) at page 9

Comment: If you do as stated in my solution. It will work. I guess they added this info because somebody filed my problem as a bug...

Answer (score 0):

Played with the workaround till Apple guys fix it. If you have xcode 6.2 installed,  symlink the 8.2 device support from Xcode 6.2 into Xcode 6.3 beta.

```
ln -s "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/8.2 (12D508)" /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/8.2
```

Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this without installing the stable version of XCode (~3.5GB download) to register my iOS device. (Other answers propose that you install the other XCode version.)

FIX: iOS devices can be registered for development manually as well (i.e. without XCode). Here are the steps http://support.smartbear.com/viewarticle/63764/

P.S. - It took me only about 10mins to complete this process manually. Requires iTunes (to read the devices UDID) and 'admin' access to the member centre.